# How can i connect my anular js front-end to two socket differernt connections which are running on two express server

Tags: angularjs, sockets, express

I have a web app(front-end angular js) that has a socket connection to my express server which works. Now i have to add another socket connection which listen to events from  a different server. Can i do this ? Is there any docs i can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to socket io [docs](https://socket.io/docs/) . Look up io.connect

```
var server1_socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.1:3000');
var server2_socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.1:3001');

server1_socket.on('server1_connection', function (data) {
  console.log('Server 1 connection');
});

server2_socket.on('server2_connection', function (data) {
  console.log('Server 2 connection');
});
```

You can you [angular-socket-io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-socket-io) which exposes a socket factory for instantiating sockets.